# jQuery failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a particular piece of jQuery that is working fine in IE9, Chrome and Firefox, etc, however IE8 seems to particularly dislike it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bandwidth").ForceNumericOnly();    
    $("#bandwidth").on("input", function() {
        var total = this.value*0.18;
        $('#total').val('£'+ total.toFixed(2));
    });
</script>
```

This takes the input from the **bandwidth** input, calculates accordingly and then writes to the **total** input, prefixed with £.

It doesn't seem to perform the calculation in to the **total** input which is really confusing me.

Comment: And what is the error given bij IE8?

Comment: The problem you are facing is that IE8 doesn't have "input" event, was added just form IE9.

Comment: There isn't any errors, even when checking in the developer console of IE8. It just simply does not perform the calculation.

Comment: input event is not supported in IE8 :) http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

Comment: use instead of oninput onkeyup or onkeypress and onpaste

Comment: Aha! Thank you. Is there any alternative to doing this in IE8 in that case?

Answer (score 3):

DEMO http://jsbin.com/acigaj/2

You can use the keyup event this event works fine in IE7+

```
$("#bandwidth").on("keyup", function() {
  var total = this.value*0.18;
  $('#total').val('£'+ total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Edit: If you want restrict the input field to numbers only? Then you can do something like this.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/acigaj/5/edit

```
$("#bandwidth").on("keyup", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/,'');
  var total = this.value*0.18;
  $('#total').val('£'+ total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For IE8 you may want to have a combination of keyup keydown events or propertychange event ... acts like input event and was added from IE6+

Maybe this will help :

http://jsbin.com/okusov/2

```
$(function(){
    $('#helloMama').on('propertychange', function(e){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('#output').text("cought by IE6+ :"+$this.val());
    });
    $('#helloMama').on('input', function(e){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('#output').text("cought by smarties: "+$this.val());
    });
 });
```